# How to setAttribute in cell td HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

**this is my script  but it doesn't work:**

```
var first = document.getElementById("sheet").rows[0];
var two = first.cells(4);
two.setAttribute('style','display:none');
```

Comment: -1 for too specific. BTW, a function is not an attribute. Review your documentation..

Comment: what element is #sheet? what is your markup?

Comment: What should `first.Cell(4)` actually do? Because it probably doesn't, anyway.

Comment: IvanSolntsev: table id |===| mavrosxristoforos: yes nothing attribute cell

Comment: Did you checked the console for any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [*cells*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#dom-tr-cells) isn't a function or method, it's a property that returns an HTML collection that can be accessed by index:

```
var two = first.cells[4];
```

Rather than using *setAttribute*, just set the property directly:

```
two.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: This answer shouldn't be selected as the correct one, the question is how to setAttribute in cell td, not how to change the style with CSS. Probably the question is not formulated properly either.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if youre really trying to set attribute OR add function onBlur - I will answer both

**If you want to set an *ATTRIBUTE*:**

<del>Then your approach is actually right -</del> considering `two` is a HTMLObject

```
two.setAttribute("class","unchecked"); //this sets class .unchecked to the "two"
```

This **replaces** all existing classes with the new class, fine if you only ever use just 1 class.

Historically you'd have work your own class merging, but for **modern browsers**, there is much more convenient way: **`two.classList.add("unchecked");`** which **adds to existing class list instead of replacing it**, but *only if the class is not there yet :-)*

**If you want to add a *FUNCTION()* which would fire *onBlur***

Then you have to use something to bind - the easiest way is to add a function inside an HTMLObject attribute(property) - notice! HTMLObject attribute (property) IS NOT the same as attribute you see inside your html code:

```
two.onblur=function(){  /*SomeJavaScriptCode*/ };
```

**or** if you already have a function:

`two.onblur = cekUndo;`

- NOTICE! there are no  () brackets - the onblur will run the function when its needed you dont want the function to fire immediatly...
- I recommend you also to check a .addEventListener method - it is more adjustable and you can add e.g. more functions on one event

Note: You can do `<td onblur="myFunction()">` - add it directly to HTML, but I dont think you can do that on the run like this you have to bind :) ...

**EDIT:** as to your second problem - as RobG said, you have to access the `cells` collection with [] brackets:

```
var two = first.cells[4];
```

Also **check** if you are actually have a cell of that **index** 
(cells are indexed from 0 to X => index 4 means 5th )

Comment: could you provide also the HTML? It is kinda hard to guess where the JS mistake is when there is no HTML :)

Comment: <table id="sheet" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>CELLROW 0</td>
    <td>CELLROW 1</td>
    <td>CELLROW 2</td>
    <td>CELLROW 3</td>
    <td>CELLROW 4</td>
    <td>CELLROW 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: syntax is running. Thank You ALL, :)